# How to make python use my installed latest openssl version?

Tags: python, openssl, centos

Environment: centos

I've installed a newer version of openssl, which can be validated by

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
```

I created a python script called test.py as follows:

```py
import ssl

print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)
```

By executing it it still shows a older version:

```
$ python test.py
OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
```

How can I uninstall the older version totally and make python use my installed latest version?

Comment: You will have to recompile Python agaist the new version of the lib.

Comment: @KlausD. Can you share the detailed steps?